# Windows IoT Core Support for Raspberry PI 3 Model B+

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

Does anyone know when is Windows IoT Core is expected to officially support Raspberry Pi Model 3 B+?

I've got a project that I need to procure the hardware for - and I'm hesitant to do that before the support is out of the preview.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi 3B+ is still in a technical preview and there is currently no timeline for a release version.

For a better evaluation experience and for any commercial products, please use the Raspberry Pi 3B or other devices with supported Intel, Qualcomm, or NXP SoCs.

If there are any reasons as to why you cannot use the 3B over the 3B+ for a production solution, please file an issue on our GitHub, [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-iotcore-docs/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No reason that we can't use RPi 3B rather than 3B+, other than 3B+ is a newer version and I would expect the support for that to last longer. Also, they have better performance, power over ethernet and 5ghz wifi.  None of these are critical - it just would be nice to invest in the latest version of the hardware.

Comment: @NickGoloborodko Thanks for sharing your reason for selecting 3B+.